# To fetch and edit image inside tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce

**I need to find an image with a file path (file_path) which is available inside tinymce. Since i am using jquery tinymce version. i think i can find image inside tinymce with specified file path.**

Function call from thickbox to my parent window

```
    self.parent.edit_img(title,alternate,align,file_path);
```

Function declaration in parent

```
    function edit_img(title,alternate,align,file_path)
        {
            var content=tinyMCE.get('comment').getContent();
            alert('Image path: '+file);
            alert(content);
        }
```

---

Help me to fetch image inside tinymce and i need to edit that image attributes

Comment: +1 for formatign and good description of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for my problem is here**
Function call from thickbox to my parent window

```
 self.parent.edit_img(title,alternate,align,file_path);
```

Function declaration in parent

```
function edit_img(title,alternate,align,file_path)
{
 file=decodeURIComponent(file);
 //To get image name from image_path
 file_arr=file.split('/');
 file=file_arr[file_arr.length-1];

 //Checking image inside tinymce and changing its edited attributes
 tinymce.activeEditor.$("img[src$='"+file+"']").attr({'alt' : alternate , 'align' : align , 'title' : title});    

}
```

---

Description
Since i use many images i need to identify which image i am editing so i checked with

```
$("img[src$='"+file+"']")
```

In this way i had edited images via calling thick box and updating specific image inside tinymce, Thank you

Comment: +1 for a solid solution; one thing to add: if using several instances of tinymce on one page be aware that tinymce.activeEditor could point to another tinymce instance with focus (i.e. when you type in one editor and push a button in the other)